# Does the Android Management API /devices have a latency

Tags: android-management-api

We currently have a problem with a google api :

> https://androidmanagement.googleapis.com/v1/enterprises/<our_enterprise>/devices/<device_name>

This API returns information about a named device, including information about its applications. We noticed a difference between what the api is returning to us is one of our phones.
Our phone has an updated application (21.05) but, the api always returns the previous version (21.01). This is problematic regarding the support of the phones because we can't have a reliable and instantaneous information of the applications installed on the phone.
Do you know if this api has a latency time to return the right data or if it is a bug?

Sincerely.
Adrien.

Answer (score 0):

As tested, there is latency time to return the data when getting application reports. I am unable to determine the exact delay time.

Currently, there is no concrete way to easily get the application reports at the exact time. However, if there is an update in the policy, then query an application report, the updated application report can be acquired. I suggest that you update a policy that will not directly affect your device and then query the report.

Please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56837897/application-reports-take-lot-of-time-to-get-updated) for additional information.