# android-management-api - Installed Application is not reflecting in Device Object .only reflected after giving sync in Android device Policy

Tags: android-management-api

After device enrolled, policy is updated with some apps.
Policy Reflected in device, application is started to download.
At that time, if we call [get device](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/get) and see the device Object, Applications are present in [Noncompliance Detail](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices#noncompliancedetail) Object with 'IN Progress' status.

After Installation Completed also, if we call [get device](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/get) and see the device Object, Applications still in [Noncompliance Detail](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices#noncompliancedetail) Object with 'IN Progress' status.

It does not Showed in [Application Report](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices#applicationreport) Object.

Applications not reflected to Device Object after Applied to the device.

It Reflected Only After we give sync in Android device Policy/reboot device/ apply another Policy.

Is there any Solution to solve this?

Comment: This is a known issue. Ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57900783/android-device-policy-sync-does-not-work-until-done-manually

Comment: @Sudhu for me, policy reflected to the device. but installed application is not reflecting to the device object. I think this one is different.

Answer (score 0):

There is latency time to return the data when getting application reports especially while the device is finishing initial provisioning.

You can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56837897/application-reports-take-lot-of-time-to-get-updated) for more information.